# Google Sheets Javascript Function Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a Google Sheets JS function that will read the data in a certain cell, call an API in regards to that value, parse the data and return the result in the cell next to the original.

I can make this happen on a one by one basis, but I'm trying to make it loop through a set of arrays.

When I run the function it's ending with only the last index call results.

Am I going about this entirely wrong, or just missing something?

```
//Create button on Sheet in dropdown
function onOpen() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.createMenu('Overwatch API Menu')
        .addItem('Get Updated Stats','ovrstat')
        .addToUi();
};
var nameCell = ["A2","A3","A4","A5"];
var rate = ["B2","B3","B4","B5"];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i = i + 1){
    var rangeA = nameCell[i];
    var rangeB = rate[i];
    function ovrstat() {
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
        var name = sheet.getRange(rangeA).getValue();
         // Call the Ovrstat API
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://ovrstat.com/stats/psn/'+name);
        var json = response.getContentText();
        var data = JSON.parse(json);
        Logger.log(data.rating);

        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
        sheet.getRange(rangeB).setValue([data.rating]);
    };
};
```

Comment: You don't call the function `ovrstat`? I also wonder by you define a function inside a loop. Just have the code that is in that function, and drop the function wrapper.

Comment: I updated my code, I added a ui button in sheets to call the function

Comment: But it makes no sense to place function inside a loop, and then call the function from somewhere else. Did you expect the function to be executed in a loop? Because that is not going to happen... You should move the line with `function ovrstat() {` *before* the line `var nameCell = ` (and adapt the indentation of your code accordingly).

Comment: I suggest you look at some JavaScript tutorials to learn the difference between a function definition and a function call.

Comment: Thanks guys, Moving  `function ovrstat() {` before the line `var nameCell =` worked. My first go at doing anything like this and I was just confused by what I had read I guess.